# jQuery Select2: [object Window] in tags value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-select2

I work With Select2 Plugin for show tags.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tags").select2({
        tags: true,
        minimumInputLength: 3,
        tokenSeparators: [','],
        createSearchChoice: function (term) {
            return {
                id: $.trim(term),
                text: $.trim(term)
            };
        },
        ajax: {
            url: "./controller/citynames.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: function (term, page) {
                return {
                    q: term
                };
            },
            results: function (data, page) {
                return {
                    results: data
                };
            }
        },

        // Take default tags from the input value
        initSelection: function (element, callback) {
            var data = [];

            function splitVal(string, separator) {
                var val, i, l;
                if (string === null || string.length < 1) return [];
                val = string.split(separator);
                for (i = 0, l = val.length; i < l; i = i + 1) val[i] = $.trim(val[i]);
                return val;
            }

            $(splitVal(element.val(), ",")).each(function () {
                data.push({
                    text: this
                });
            });

            callback(data);
        },

        // Some nice improvements:

        // max tags is 3
        maximumSelectionSize: 5,

        // override message for max tags
        formatSelectionTooBig: function (limit) {
            return "Max tags is only " + limit;
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" id="tags" value="test1,test2," style="width: 400px;">
```

Now I have two problem :

1- I html action I have two `value="test1,test2,"` but in html output I see only one value : `test1` !!

2- I inspect elements I see 3 value : `test1,test2,[object Window]`

Images: ( this Demo @ my localhost )

[image]

DEMO @ [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X6V2s/13/)

How do can I Fix This Problem?!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add id in your initSelection

```
data.push({
    id:this,
    text: this
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/X6V2s/13/